# Which SXA components should be cached for minimal setup?

Tags: sxa, caching

I'm reviewing the cache settings available in SXA found [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/setting_up/set_sxa_caching_options). There are many components that are available for caching, but I'm not clear whether any should not be cached.

In an effort to start simple:
Which components can be configured for caching that maximize the caching on the  page?

**Example:** You can add the `PartialDesign Dynamic Placeholder` and it will cache everything!

[image: Caching Setting]

#### Update

2021.03.03

Turns out that if you cache the PartialDesign, Splitters, and Containers it has the outcome of interfering with some of the other caching. Still need to figure out how to cache the entire page after it's constructed.

2019.06.21

Decided to not spend too much time researching (someone say lazy developer?) so i went with the list below. A few are custom components.

[image: Example Setup]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Cache Html` option from the

`/sitecore/content/Your tenant/Your demoSXA/Settings/Site Grouping/Your demoSXA`

`Your demoSXA` is your site name here.

[image]

You can setup the Cache on the components which renders data from field and can ignore the Markup only components like, Containers, Splitters, Dividers, etc.
Setup the followings, and you will see the darastic results.

[image]

Component Level cache can also be enabled from: 
`Presentation > Cache Settings > Component Cache Setting` 
and select the caches you want to apply on the components.

[image]

Reference Link:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/setting_up/set_sxa_caching_options

Comment: This answer does not make use of the cache settings item introduced in 1.7. I do have the cache html option selected on the site item. What I'm looking for is guidance using the sxa specific feature.